# implementing a "findM" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a function that basically is like `mapM` on a list -- it performs a series of monadic actions taking every value in the list as a parameter -- and each monadic function returns `m (Maybe b)`.   However, I want it to stop after the first parameter that causes the function to return a `Just` value, not execute any more after that, and return that value.

Well, it'll probably be easier to just show the type signature:

```
findM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> [a] -> m (Maybe b)
```

where b is the first `Just` value.  The `Maybe` in the result is from the `find`ing (in case of an empty list, etc.), and has nothing to do with the `Maybe` returned by the Monadic function.

I can't seem to implement this with a straightforward application of library functions.  I could use

```
findM f xs = fmap (fmap fromJust . find isJust) $ mapM f xs
```

which will work, but I tested this and it seems that **all** of the monadic actions are executed before calling `find`, so I can't rely on laziness here.

```
ghci> findM (\x -> print x >> return (Just x)) [1,2,3]
1
2
3
-- returning IO (Just 1)
```

What is the best way to implement this function that won't execute the monadic actions after the first "just" return?  Something that would do:

```
ghci> findM (\x -> print x >> return (Just x)) [1,2,3]
1
-- returning IO (Just 1)
```

or even, ideally,

```
ghci> findM (\x -> print x >> return (Just x)) [1..]
1
-- returning IO (Just 1)
```

Hopefully there is an answer that doesn't use explicit recursion, and are compositions of library functions if possible?  Or maybe even a **point-free** one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One simple point-free solution is using the `MaybeT` transformer. Whenever we see `m (Maybe a)` we can wrap it into `MaybeT` and we get all `MonadPlus` functions immediately. Since `mplus` for `MaybeT` does exactly we need - it runs the second given action only if the first one resulted in `Nothing` - `msum` does exactly what we need:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

findM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> [a] -> m (Maybe b)
findM f = runMaybeT . msum . map (MaybeT . f)
```

---

**Update:** In this case, we were lucky that there exists a monad transformer (`MaybeT`) whose `mplus` has just the semantic we need. But in a general case, it can be that it won't be possible to construct such a transformer. `MonadPlus` has some laws that must be satisfied with respect to other monadic operations. However, all is not lost, as we actually don't need a `MonadPlus`, all we need is a proper [**monoid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) to fold with.

So let's pretend we don't (can't) have `MaybeT`. Computing the first value of some sequence of operations is described by the [`First`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) monoid. We just need to make a monadic variant that won't execute the right part, if the left part has a value:

```
newtype FirstM m a = FirstM { getFirstM :: m (Maybe a) }
instance (Monad m) => Monoid (FirstM m a) where
    mempty = FirstM $ return Nothing
    mappend (FirstM x) (FirstM y) = FirstM $ x >>= maybe y (return . Just)
```

This monoid exactly describes the process without any reference to lists or other structures. Now we just fold over the list using this monoid:

```
findM' :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> [a] -> m (Maybe b)
findM' f = getFirstM . mconcat . map (FirstM . f)
```

Moreover, it allows us to create a more generic (and even shorter) function using `Data.Foldable`:

```
findM'' :: (Monad m, Foldable f)
        => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> f a -> m (Maybe b)
findM'' f = getFirstM . foldMap (FirstM . f)
```

Comment: Hah! It seems we had the exact same idea at the same time. You were a bit faster though. :)

Comment: Yes. `mzero` and `mplus` in the `MonadPlus` instance for `Maybe` are exactly the same as the `empty` and `<|>` in the `Alternative` instance for `Maybe`. `MaybeT`'s `mzero` and `mplus` are `return Nothing` and the '<||>' function I defined, except written with a case like my original answer and jozefg's answer. All we are missing for a complete treatise on the subject is an explanation of how to go from seeing `(Monad m) => m . f` to writing a monad transformer for f so that you can replace `m . f` with a new data type so you can start writing instances for it.

Comment: @Cirdec I updated the answer. In a general case it might not be possible to construct such a transformer, but we don't actually need one. It's enough to have a monoid and fold over it.

Answer (score 9):

I like Cirdec's answer if you don't mind recursion, but I think the equivalent fold based answer is quite pretty.

```
findM f = foldr test (return Nothing) 
    where test x m = do
              curr <- f x 
              case curr of
                  Just _  -> return curr
                  Nothing -> m
```

A nice little test of how well you understand folds.

Comment: is there a way I can do this in terms of Alternative's `<|>`?  It seems so close to being able to be point-free

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
findM _ [] = return Nothing
findM filter (x:xs) =
    do
        match <- filter x
        case match of
             Nothing -> findM filter xs
             _ -> return match
```

**If you really want to do it points free (added as an edit)**

The following would find something in a list using an `Alternative` functor, using a fold as in jozefg's answer

```
findA :: (Alternative f) => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f b
findA = flip foldr empty . ((<|>) .)
```

I don't thing we can make `(Monad m) => m . Maybe` an instance of `Alternative`, but we could pretend there's an existing function:

```
-- Left biased choice
(<||>) :: (Monad m) => m (Maybe a) -> m (Maybe a) -> m (Maybe a)
(<||>) left right = left >>= fromMaybe right . fmap (return . Just)
-- Or its hideous points-free version
(<||>) = flip ((.) . (>>=)) (flip ((.) . ($) . fromMaybe) (fmap (return . Just)))
```

Then we can define `findM` in the same vein as `findA`

```
findM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> [a] -> m (Maybe b)
findM = flip foldr (return Nothing) . ((<||>) .)
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be expressed pretty nicely with the [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) monad transformer and [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html).

```
import Data.Foldable (msum)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..))

findM :: Monad m => (a -> m (Maybe b)) -> [a] -> m (Maybe b)
findM f = runMaybeT . msum . map (MaybeT . f)
```

And if you change your search function to produce a `MaybeT` stack, it becomes even nicer:

```
findM' :: Monad m => (a -> MaybeT m b) -> [a] -> MaybeT m b
findM' f = msum . map f
```

Or in point-free:

```
findM' = (.) msum . map
```

The original version can be made fully point-free as well, but it becomes pretty unreadable:

```
findM = (.) runMaybeT . (.) msum . map . (.) MaybeT
```